# Windows 10 KIOSK - immediate logout after login (multiscreen error)

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, kiosk

I have problem with kiosk mode. After automatic login user is logged out after few milliseconds when KIOSK is configured and multiple monitors are connected. Removing monitors and restart results in correct working KIOSK. I looked through internet and found some interesting solutions e.g. [Editing registry entry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8091599-13a8-496c-94fe-1824f8be061d/assigned-access-immediately-logoff-after-login?forum=win10itprosetup), but they not working too.

This problem exists both on virtual machine and physical PC's. For virtual machine tests i'm using [Win 10 image for developers](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/) with latest updates - virtual box with 3 monitors configured, 8 cores, 8GB of RAM.

I created kiosk settings based on this articles: [Win 10 kiosk multi app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps), [multiapp kiosk xml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-xml) and configured it based on [MDM bridge for kiosk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-mdm-bridge).

Configuration schema is following:

1. Create kiosk account
2. Configure automatic login by editing registry
3. Restart
4. Configure kiosk using MDM bridge
5. Restart

Unfortunately, after last restart user logs in and logs out immediately. Interesting event log entries are listed below:

- [Windows Logs/System](https://github.com/TheHunterPL/SharedLogs/blob/master/Win10KioskMultiscreen/2021-01-20/text/System.md)
- [Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/AssignedAccess/Admin](https://github.com/TheHunterPL/SharedLogs/blob/master/Win10KioskMultiscreen/2021-01-20/text/ASAdmin.md)
- [Applications and ServicesLogs/Microsoft/Windows/AssignedAccess/Operational](https://github.com/TheHunterPL/SharedLogs/blob/master/Win10KioskMultiscreen/2021-01-20/text/ASOperational.md)

I tested same configuration on physical PC with Win 10 Pro, but problem still exists.